# Getting intent extra value with Espresso

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I have an app where either one activity (let's call it `ActivityA`) or another (`ActivityB`) can lead to the same target activity (`ActivityC`).

In my code, `ActivityC` has a button that leads back to the previous activity: either `ActivityA` or `ActivityB`, depending on which one has called `ActivityC`.

I'd like to write some unit tests with Espresso to validate this flow but don't know how to figure out which activity has called `ActivityC`. The code below illustrates my problem:

```
String extra = getIntent().getStringExtra("key"); // How can I store the extra value?
if (ActivityA.class.getName().equals(extra)) {
    intended(hasComponent(ActivityA.class.getName()));
} else if (ActivityB.class.getName().equals(extra)) {
    intended(hasComponent(ActivityB.class.getName()));
}
```

Having this accomplished, my test will be able to validate whether the intent is pointing towards the correct target activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out that Espresso doesn't have methods that can do what I was trying to, given the fact that the responsibility of validating whether `ActivityC` was leading back to its previous activity lies within the unit tests for both `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`.

Basically what has been done to solve the issue was to make `ActivityA` (or B) call `ActivityC` and then have `ActivityC` call its previous activity in its own way, regardless of which one it is.